# how do I get the program to Know which annotation is selected and be able to access properties of it?

Tags: iphone, sdk, mkmapview, mkannotation, viewcontroller

So far my program can display a database of custom annotation views. Eventually I want my program to be able to display extra information after a button on the annotation bubble is clicked. Each element in the database has a unique entry Number, so I thought it would be a good idea to add this entry number as a property of the custom annotation. The problem I am having is that after the button is clicked and the program switches to a new view I am unable to retrieve the entry number of the annotation I selected. 
Below is the code that assigns the entry Number property to the annotation:

```
for (id mine in mines)
 {
 workingCoordinate.latitude = [[mine latitudeInitial] doubleValue];
 workingCoordinate.longitude = [[mine longitudeInitial] doubleValue];
 iProspectAnnotation *tempMine = [[iProspectAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
 [tempMine setTitle:[mine mineName]];
 [tempMine setAnnotationEntryNumber:[mine entryNumber]];  
   }
[mines dealloc];
```

When the button on an annotation is selected, this is the code that initializes the new view:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control 
{ 
mineInformationController *controller = [[mineInformationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"mineInformationController" bundle:nil];

controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
   }
```

and lastly is my attempt at retrieving the entryNumber property from the new view so that I can compare it to the mines database and retrieve more information on the array element.

```
iProspectFresno_LiteAppDelegate *appDelegate = (iProspectFresno_LiteAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSMutableArray* mines = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:(NSMutableArray *)appDelegate.mines];
for(id mine in mines)
{
 if ([[mine entryNumber] isEqualToNumber: /*the entry Number of the selected annotation*/])
       { 
       /* display the information in the mine object */
       }
  }
```

So how do I access this entry number property in this new view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, you are gonna have to tag your annotations. Just check this out, it's definitely gonna help you:

http://www.everydayone.com/2009/08/mapkit_annotations/

Comment: So is the UIViewController park of the Mapkit Framework? or in this case is it the AnnotationView?